# Vim's remote-send, without intermediate redraws?

Tags: clientserver, redraw

I'm using Vim as a (debugger) frontend, but am bothered by the "flickering" screens when sending multiple commands at once. My current setup already uses `lazyredraw` that [should work for functions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6157/12612). I communicate with a vim session using:

```
> vim --server "<servername>" --remote-send "<command>"
```

I basically send a unique function every time and then execute it, such that I can take advantage of lazyredraw. A typical `<command>` looks like:

```
:silent execute "function! Mycommands()\n \
vim test/src/main.cc\n                    \
execute "sign place 5 line=5 name=<SOMESIGN> file=" . expand("%:p")\n \
call cursor(5,1)\n                        \
redraw!\n                                 \
endfunction" |                            \
call Mycommands()<Enter>
```

It (1) opens a file, (2) highlights line 5 using a vim `sign`, and (3) moves the cursor to line 5.

If I record my vim session and slow it down, I see how this `<command>` is printed to the vim command line (It actually increase the cmd area for these long `<command>`'s), I then see how the file is opened, and lastly how the sign is placed. My questions are:

1) can I stop redrawing, send my commands, and then redraw?
2) can I disable the echoing of `<command>` to the vim commandline, like possible with a mapping using `<silent>`?
3) Is there a better way to achieve the frontend setup that avoids this issue?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one workaround is to write an tempfile with the command(s) in them.
Then send a command to source this file. like in

```
> vim --server "<servername>" --remote-send "so /path/to/tempfile"
```

Comment: This approach works if I change the command to `":so[urce] /path/to/tempfile<Enter>"` and remove the `redraw!`. Although I do now see the command in the vim commandline al the time.. I fixed this in an ungly way by adding `i<Esc>` at the end. Is there a better way to achieve this?