# stop updating screen until function finishes or manually call redraw

Tags: vim-windows

Does vim/neovim have the ability to manually disable screen updating? I run a function that jumps between a few tabs, update the content, and then go back to the original tab. The screen then flash several times. Is there a way to freeze screen until I execute redraw later?

I see there is a command noautocmd to disable autocommands temporarily, but did find a similar mechanism for noredraw.

Isn't this function easy to implement and also very useful for many cases?

Comment: Does setting the `'lazyredraw'` option temporarily help (`set lz`)?

Comment: no not possible currently. You might try setting `lazyredraw` but it won't disable redrawing completely.

Comment: Related question: [vimscript - Prevent refresh of screen until function completes - Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3854/prevent-refresh-of-screen-until-function-completes?noredirect=1&lq=1). There's no general question, but in this specific case there is a workaround.